# Recursion when randomizing elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, random, pure-function, infinite-loop

I want to randomize certain elements of a list; Since the code

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
list[[{1, 3, 5}]] = RandomSample@list[[{1, 3, 5}]];
list
```

works fine, I was trying to see if I could speed up things a little bit and have only one call to `list[[{1,3,5}]]` using a pure function

The code

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
(# = RandomSample@#) &[list[[{1, 3, 5}]]];
list
```

will trigger an infinite recursion. I know that the function evaluates the argument before passing to the function, but the infinite recursion still confuses me.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: The problem with the pure function approach is that this pure function doesn't have a HoldAll attribute so `list[[{1, 3, 5}]]` is evaluated *before* it is substituted in `#`, so you end up with `{a,c,d} = RandomSample[{a,c,d}]` (i.e. creating cyclic definitions for these three symbols) instead of the correct `list[[{1,3,5}]] = RandomSample[{a,c,d}]`.  To fix this, use `Function[x, x=RandomSample[x], HoldAll]`.  However, this approach won't help in speeding up your code.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Your comment should be posted as answer.

Comment: Is the question just about the recursion behavior, or is there an over-arching goal, e.g. creating some large number of such lists rapidly?

Comment: Both: my question was initially on the recursion, but the final goal would be to be able to create a large number of (fairly big) such lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the faster generation part of your query, something like the following should be useful if you're needing a large number of tinkered lists:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p};
positions = {3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15};
numtomake = 100000;

(** naive generation **)
Table[(list[[positions]] = RandomSample@list[[positions]]; 
    list), {numtomake}]; // Timing

(** precomputing samples *)
(elements = list[[positions]];
  listTargets = ConstantArray[list, numtomake];
  permutations = Table[RandomSample[elements], {numtomake}];
  listTargets[[All, positions]] = permutations;) // Timing

(* 2.293215 *)
(* 0.936006 *)
```

So about 2.5X faster in my minimal tests, probably better as list size/number of possible permutation candidates, and number of lists needed increase.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Do you know why is latter faster?

Comment: @user2397318: Pretty standard *MMA* fare: any time you can do things in "bulk" (the copy with "All") vs separate calls, it will be faster, and for some things (e.g. certain array operations) *MMA* will use sorcery under the covers (like divide-and-conquer) to speed things up.